# CakePHP show Next / Previous link for posts

Tags: cakephp

The CakePHP Blog Tutorial shows a pagination view of all Blog posts.
If in the view mode of a blog entry, how would I show a previous/next link to the posts before and after this one?
Rather than having an index page with all posts listed I would like to click in blog view from post to post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/449/find):

`find('neighbors', $params)`

> 'neighbors' will perform a find
>   similar to 'first', but will return
>   the row before and after the one you
>   request. Below is a simple (controller
>   code)

Example:

```
function some_function() {
   $neighbors = $this->Article->find('neighbors', array('fields' => 'id', 'value' => 3));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for.
But how would I show it in view.cpt, that is what is the code to use and display the function?

Comment: @star Pass the id of the neighbors to the view and display a link to them there.

Answer (score 0):

You can user the [`Post->find('neighbor')`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data#find-neighbors-1024) function for that.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice explanation for this topic has been given here

[Previous Next posts links in Cakephp](http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2015/01/generate-previous-next-posts-link-in.html)